# Firefox errors out with "Certificate not yet valid"

Tags: git, macos, firefox, certificate

ALL,

I recently bought myself a new Mac and it was working fine for a while.
However recently I had problem with Comcast and now nothing works.

Firefox errors out with `mozilla_pkix_error_not_yet_valid_certificate` and git does not recognise the certs.

IIUC, I can change the date time on the Mac, but I don't want to screw up the date/time settings on it.

Is there a way to fix everything properly.

I tried to reboot the laptop and when I started FF it installs a new version, but I still get the same error.

TIA!

Comment: It's hard to say for certain from your description, but my first guess is that the clock on your Mac is set wrong. So the first question is: what does your Mac think the date is? What are the settings in the Date & Time preferences? If that's set correctly, the next question is exactly when these errors are occurring (which websites are getting the error, what cert is git not recognizing, etc)?

Comment: @GordonDavisson, you were right! for some unknown reason the Comcast issue broke the date/time only on this specific Mac. No Windows, no Linux and not even older Mac were problematic. Very weird, but... So after fixing the date/time everything works again...